# Always show empty weeks

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to be able to show all week numbers per month regardless of whether there are hours for that week or not.

Change this:

```
2.00    2    July
2.25    3    July
7.25    5    July
```

To this:

```
0.00    1    July
2.00    2    July
2.25    3    July
0.00    4    July
7.25    5    July
```

Here is the current query I am working with:

```
SELECT  SUM(te.Hours_Bill) AS HoursBilled
     ,  DATEPART(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, te.Date_Start) / 7 * 7 ) / 7 + 1 AS HoursWeekNumber
     ,  DATENAME(mm, te.Date_Start) AS HoursMonthName

 FROM   AGR_Header ah
        INNER 
        JOIN Time_Entry te
          ON te.Agr_Header_RecID = ah.AGR_Header_RecID
        INNER 
        JOIN Company co
          ON co.Company_RecID = ah.Company_RecID

 WHERE  (te.Date_Start >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) -6, 0) AND te.Date_Start <= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, -1, GETDATE()) -1, -1))

 GROUP
    BY  DATEPART(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, te.Date_Start) / 7 * 7 ) / 7 + 1
     ,  DATENAME(mm, te.Date_Start)
     ,  DATEPART(mm, te.Date_Start)

 ORDER
    BY  DATEPART(mm, te.Date_Start) ASC
     ,  DATEPART(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, te.Date_Start) / 7 * 7 ) / 7 + 1 ASC
```

By default I want to show all week numbers for a month and if no results for the week, display 0.

Comment: Use an outer join on a table (or CTE) of "week numbers per month".

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
CREATE TABLE #t
  (
     hr     NUMERIC(22, 6),
     weekno INT,
     mon    VARCHAR(20)
  )

INSERT INTO #t
VALUES
(2.00  ,  2 ,   'October'),
(2.25  ,  3  ,  'October'),
(7.25  ,  5  ,  'October')

WITH dates AS (
     SELECT 1 id,datename(month,(getdate())) mon
     UNION ALL
       SELECT  id+1, mon FROM dates WHERE id<5
)
SELECT Isnull(hr, 0) hrs,
       id    AS weekno,
       d.mon AS [month]
FROM   #t t
       RIGHT JOIN dates d
               ON t.mon = d.mon
                  AND t.weekno = d.id
```

output

```
hrs       weekno    month
0.000000    1       October
2.000000    2       October
2.250000    3       October
0.000000    4       October
7.250000    5       October
```